# OnNavigatedTo is not populating a string, Why?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

This was working, and I have no clue why it stopped.

My mainPage.xaml has the following code to open a new page:

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string fileNotRead = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt";       

    MessageBox.Show("on Main: " + fileNotRead);
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/pickIt.xaml?arr=" + fileNotRead, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

On the second form I have the following

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    string fileToOpen = string.Empty;
    MessageBox.Show("Navigation received");

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("arr", out fileToOpen))
    {
        param = fileToOpen;
        MessageBox.Show("On Pick: " + fileToOpen);
    }

    param = fileToOpen;

}
```

param is a public String, and I have tried this a few different ways.

I am not getting the inner most messageBox to show the TryGetValue was successful, and if I try to use Param I get ArgumentNullException (As would be expected).

Also, the current TryGetValue is new, but only because my original approach is what mysteriously broke. The original approach was:

```
param = Uri.UnescapeDataString(NavigationContext.QueryString["arr"]);
```

Any pointers or next steps appreciated! But most importantly, why is this not working?

Comment: What is the value of `fileNotRead`? Does it contain any characters that could break the query string syntax?

Comment: @DamirArh No, simple text file names. djfhdh.txt, apples.txt. Simple names like that, nothing that escaped / unescaped should break.

Answer (score 0):

try this

first page

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
string fileNotRead = (listBox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString()+ ".txt";   
MessageBox.Show("on Main: " + fileNotRead);
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/pickIt.xaml?arr=" + fileNotRead, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

second page

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  string fileToOpen = null;
  bool availability= NavigationContext.QueryString.Keys.Contains("arr");
       if (availability)
       {
           fileToOpen  = NavigationContext.QueryString["arr"];
           MessageBox.Show("On Pick: " + fileToOpen);
       }
       else {
           MessageBox.Show("Data Not Available");
       }
base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

}
```

Comment: Gives me an exception: "KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by user code"

Comment: Although no exception, I get ` Data not available`.